# Curtain Scroll Effect with Skrollr

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I would like to create a simple curtain effect with skrollr. I think z-index could be a good way? slide1 should be fixed and slide2 should slide from bottom to top oder slide1 and so on ...

```
<div id="slide1" data-start="z-index:1;"></div>
<div id="slide2" data-start="z-index:2;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9LF3/

Answer (score 0):

You can just add data-1000="width:100%;" data-2000="width:0%;"

```
<div id="slide1" data-start="z-index:1;" data-0="height:100%;" data-1000="height:0%;"></div>
<div id="slide2" data-start="z-index:2;" data-1000="width:100%;" data-2000="width:0%;"></div>
```